# Why does geany use #~ for comments in bash instead of just #?

Tags: bash, geany

When I select a block of text in Geany (editing a bash script) and hit Ctrl + E to comment, Geany inserts `#~` at the beginning of every line, instead of just `#`. Why?

Comment: Anything after `#` is not of any significance. A matter of style, perhaps.

Comment: @BlueMoon If it's a matter of style, it shouldn't be imposed. I prefer the `#` alone, it's simpler. Is there a setting where I can change this?

Comment: I haven't use Geany, but it sounds like your [NOPing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) a block of code (which puts the `#` in front). I suspect that Geany has a reverse function which removes the comment blocks and reactivates the code. The `#~` may allow Geany to tell the difference between blocks of code it NOPed, and your regular comments.

Comment: @DavidW. Good assuming ;) See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geany is adding the `~` after the `#` to mark these lines as been toggled. Ctrl + E is toggeling the comment in default so

```
# Original Comment
print ("Hello world")
```

becomes

```
#~ # Original Comment
#~ print ("Hello world")
```

And back again

```
# Original Comment
print ("Hello world")
```

Without some special marker it would might be hard to recognize what has been comment and what has been normal code.

Comment: +1 That makes sense. However, Geany is the first editor that I've seen that does this. Sublime Text, gEdit, and others, just use `#` and work fine. Do you know if there is a way to tell Geany to use `#` instead of `#~`?

Comment: At least you can configure it at Preferences->Editor. Keeping the field blank might would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, Preferences->Editor->Comment Toggle Marker -- if you make the Comment Toggle Marker "empty" (remove the ~) then it marks with the regular # which I really prefer.

Comment: But will cause the toggle function to don't work properly anymore.